# High CPU temperatures while using iCloud for Windows

Tags: icloud, windows, cpu, temperature

I hope you don't mind the Windows related question.
I am trying to run iCloud for Windows on my PC (running Windows 11 Pro) but when I turn on iCloud Drive, my CPU temps jump by about 15-20 deg C.  Oddly, CPU usage remains relatively low (5-8%) and nothing seems to be happening re: syncing (i.e., it looks like it is caught in a loop).  As soon, as I turn off iCloud Drive sync, the temperatures drop back to normal (~40-45 deg C).

I have tried:

- updating iCloud and Windows (both are latest versions)
- uninstalling/reinstalling iCloud (no change)
- changing priority of iCloud using Task Manager (no effect)

FYI: I am running a 5900x on a B550 motherboard (32GB RAM).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about Windows, but on macOS, I can use Activity Monitor to watch disk activity. Perhaps there's an equivalent way to see if disk usage jumps when you turn on sync.

Comment: Thanks IconDaemon.
I'm currently using HWInfo - which is very similar to Activity Monitor.  Disk activity is very low, as is CPU usage.  However, the sync has been running for about 36 hours now and the temps have dropped to about 65 deg C (from an average of 71 deg C).  The sync appears to be proceeding - but very very very slowly